# SQL - Check if a date is the first occurrence of that day in its month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have some dates that I would like to filter with SQL.

I want to be able to pass a flag to say keep all the FIRST Mondays of the months from X date to Y Date.

So essentially, I want to pass in a date and be able to tell if it's the first, second, third, fourth or last Monday (for example) of a given month.

I have already filtered down the months and days and I am currently using `DATEPART(DAY, thedate)` to check if the day is < 8 then 1 week < 15 2 week etc.... but this is not correct.

So the part I am stuck on is `Where IsDateFirstOfMonth(@date)`
Where would I start to write the function `IsDateFirstOfMonth`?
Any help much appreciated

Comment: What is wrong with checking that the day of the month is less than 8?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if `@date` is the first Monday, or if it's during the first week of the month (i.e., if it's during the same week of the year as the first date of the same month)?  It almost sounds like you're trying to do both.

Comment: Well I have a whole list of date. Lets say all the Mondays from today until the end of the year. I want the option to say return either the First or Second or Third or Forth or Last Monday in every month. so if i use the logic of >8 or >15 etc.. it wouldn't always work for the 4th or last

Comment: What if the fourth Monday is also the last Monday?

Comment: You can use the trick of subtracting 8 days from the 1st of the next month to find out if it is last.

Comment: I want the option to say is @date the First or Second or Third or Fourth or Last Monday in it's own month. ie the month it belongs to

Comment: @user2329438 kindly, check my answer after i edited it and if it helps you, please mark it as answer and if you still have any question about my answer, go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
alter function IsDateFirstOfMonth(@date as datetime)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @first datetime,
            @last datetime,
            @temp datetime,
            @appearance int
    declare @table table(Id int identity(1,1),
                         StartDate datetime,
                         EndDate datetime,
                         DayName nvarchar(20),
                         RowNumber int)
    set @first=dateadd(day,1-day(@date),@date)
    set @last=dateadd(month,1,@first)-1
    set @temp=@first
    while @temp<=@last
    begin
        insert into @table(StartDate,EndDate,DayName) values(@temp,@temp+6,datename(dw,@temp))
        set @temp=@temp +1
    end     
    select @appearance=Nb
    from(
    select StartDate,EndDate,DayName,row_number() over (partition by DayName order by StartDate) as Nb 
    from @table) t
    where @date between t.StartDate and t.EndDate and datename(dw,@date)=t.DayName

    if @last-@date<7 
      set @appearance=-1

    return @appearance
end



select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('31 Dec 2014')    
    select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('03 Nov 2014') -- result 1 ( first) monday
    select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('10 Nov 2014') -- result 2 (second)
    select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('17 Nov 2014') -- result 3 (third)
    select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('24 Nov 2014') -- result -1 (last) .... here it will be the last monday
    select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('02 Nov 2014') -- result 1 ( first) sunday
```

hope this will help you

Comment: thank you very much for you help. This works very well but only for Mondays it seems? Maybe i wasn't too clear but i was only using Monday as an example. if i remove the if check for mondays and run it using '15 Nov 2014' i get 2 instead of 3 as it is the 3rd saturday in November.  again thanks for your help. also if you don't mind explaining how all the nested datediffs work that would be most appreciated and maybe i can debug myself ;)

Comment: remove the if(datename(dw,@date)='Monday'), then it will work for all days in a week

Comment: I done that but like i said when i run it using '15 Nov 2014' i get 2 instead of the expected 3 as it is the 3rd saturday in November.cheers

Comment: Thank you very much Hadi as i know this is a tricky one. I still appear to be getting weird behaviour for dates like select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('24 DEC 2014') gives -1 when it is not the last Wednesday in Dec and 
select dbo.IsDateFirstOfMonth('05 DEC 2014') gives 0.

Comment: @user2329438 i re-write the function completely in different way, and this time this function will take the whole month and will build the weeks of this month and then partition the weeks based on the datename and at end will check the date if it is last or not, hope this time your problem will be solved

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problem it's usually much easier to implement a table with the required date information and join on tthat table, and filter using it. I.e. create a table with this info:

```
CREATE TABLE Dates(
  Date DATE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  PositionInMoth TINYINT,
  LastInMonth BIT)
```

Then fill up this table using whichever method you want. I think you'll do it much easyly with a simple ad-hoc app, but you can also create it using a T-SQL script.

Then you simply need to join your table with this one, and use the PositionInMoth or LastInMonth columns for filtering. You can also use this as a lookup table to easyly implement the required function.

By the way, don't forget that there are many months which have a fifth instance of a given day, for example, on december 2014 there are 5 Mondays, 5 Tuesdays, and 5 Wednesdays. The number of days with 5 instances in a given motnh is: number of days in the month - 28, for example, in December it's 31-28 = 3. So you can't count on the 4th being the last.

This table really takes up very little space, *roughly*, 3 bytes for the `DATE`, 1 byte for the `TINYINT`, and 1 byte for `BIT`, so it's 3+1+1 = 5 bytes per day, 1,825 bytes per year, and 178 kb for a whole century. So, even if you needed several centuries to cover all your possible dates, i would still be a very small table. I say *roughly* because the index structure, the fill factor and some other things will make the table somewhat bigger. Being such an small table means that SQL Server can easyly cache the whole table in memory when executing the queries, so your they will run really fast.

*NOTE: you can expand this table to cover other needs like checking if a day is the last in the month, or the last or first working day in a month, by adding new `BIT` columns*

Very interesting link, from OP comment: [CALENDAR TABLES IN T-SQL](http://blog.aware.co.th/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/)

Comment: Thanks JotaBe, I had found this article in the mean time and decide to go with what you suggested http://blog.aware.co.th/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all you help.
Hadi your reply worked perfectly but I have decide to use a tally table after all

I found a good example here 
http://blog.aware.co.th/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/

thanks again